# How do I connect my live https website to my AWS beanstalk back end

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, deployment, https, netlify

Ok so I have a website currently deployed through netlify and I own the domain and its a https domain. In my front end .js files I am calling it through that domain like https://example.com/api/etc... And I have a server.js file on my backend hosted in aws with a long beanstalk url which also interacts with a postgreSQL database also hosted on AWS (I dont know if that is relevant) anyways after my website was deployed and switched to https instead of http it was saying I couldn't use my http beanstalk url anymore. I set up a certificate on AWS and a CNAME on my netlify and got the certificate approved. So basically why are my calls/fetches with my https://example.com/api/etc... domain not working. Please don't yell at me I am stupid and don't know a lot.

I wanted to be able to have my frontend and backend interact